# angular2 view not updating data changed from shared service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-template

I am trying to display data coming from my shared service but it was not displaying. can anyone please help me, i struct in this from fast few days. I have tried NgZone and ChangeDetectorRef but does't work for me.

**home.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let order of orders " class="order-cards">
    <div class="order-card">
        <div class="btn-order-card">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success " (click)="viewOrder(order)">View the Order </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**home.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


import { SharedService } from '../services/shared.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor( private route: Router, private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  viewOrder(order) {
    this.route.navigate(['../view-order'])
    this.sharedService.viewOrderValues(order);
  }
  
}
```

**shared.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

Injectable()

export class SharedService {
    constructor() { }
    private viewOrderSource = new Subject<any>();

    viewOrder$ = this.viewOrderSource.asObservable();

    viewOrderValues(data: any) {
        this.viewOrderSource.next(data);
        return data;
    }
}
```

**view-order.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { SharedService } from '../services/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-order',
  template: '{{orderValues}}',
  styleUrls: ['./view-order.component.scss']
})
export class ViewOrderComponent implements OnInit {
  orderValues: any;
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.viewOrder$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.orderValues = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi All,
I changed `private viewOrderSource = new Subject<any>();` to 
`private viewOrderSource =  new BehaviorSubject<Object>(null);`
in **shared-service.ts** then It's working as expected 

Really Appreciated for all your responses .

Comment: In that case, you don't really need `BehaviourSubject` too. Simple variable in shared-service is enough - set it in one component while routing and get in another's `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
private viewOrderSource = new Subject<any>();
```

to

```
private viewOrderSource = new BehaviorSubject<Object>(null);
```

in **shared-seriice.ts**

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is wrong.

You should use the [routing based `Resolve`](https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating) and pass the param as id to the component, so that you can get the data when the component is *loaded*.

Modified your `shared.service.ts` to support id based search:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  private orders = [];  // initialize or fetch from service, IDK
  ordersChanged = new Subject<any[]>();

  constructor() { }

  addOrder(order: any) {
    this.orders.push(order);
    this.ordersChanged.next(this.getOrders());
  }

  getOrders(): any[] {
    return this.orders.slice();
  }

  getOrder(id: number) {
    // your logic to find order
    return this.orders[id];
  }
}
```

In your `home.component.html`:

```
<div *ngFor="let order of orders; let i = index" class="order-cards">
    <div class="order-card">
        <div class="btn-order-card">
            <button 
                type="submit"
                class="btn btn-success"
                (click)="viewOrder(i)">View the Order</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and correspoding change in your `home.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  orders: string[];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private route: Router, private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orders = this.sharedService.getOrders();
    this.subscription = this.sharedService.ordersChanged.subscribe(orders => this.orders = orders);
  }

  viewOrder(index: number) {
    this.route.navigate(['/view-order', index])
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

You can create an `OrderResolver` service:

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderResolver implements Resolve<any>{
    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

    resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): string | Observable<string> | Promise<string> {
        const id = +route.params['id'];
        return this.sharedService.getOrder(id);
    }

}
```

You can easily inject a `Router` in the above and handle the case when there is no order for the given id.

In your routing module class, change the `view-order` path to accept a parameter as id and use a resolver to find the order during the route loading:

```
  {
    path: 'view-order/:id',
    component: ViewOrderComponent,
    resolve: { order: OrderResolver }
  }
```

and then in your `ViewOrderComponent`:

```
export class ViewOrderComponent implements OnInit {
  orderValues: any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orderValues = this.route.snapshot.data['order'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @GurV. I using same shared concept for another component it's working everything fine but the only issue was view was not updating with data came through subscribe method in **view-order.component.ts**  and one more thing I was able to log the data from **shared-service** and **view-order.component.ts** in console.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the list to a copy of the data. The angular wont realize its changed unless you reset the data to an entirely different object or array.

You can use this.arrayName = this.arrayName.slice() for an array;
Or for an object
var objName = Object.assign({}, objName)

Comment: Thanks for your response 
that means should I do like this in view-order.component.ts subscribe method. If i am wrong please correct me.
`this.orderValues = Object.assign({}, this.orderValues);
this.orderValues = data;`

Comment: hmmm no, it would be more like this.orderValues = Object.assign({}, data);

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

```
this.sharedService.viewOrderValues(order);
this.route.navigate(['../view-order'])
```

I feel you are navigating first so it is not calling that function and hence your observer is not being invoked.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Indraneel Bende I tried this way as well but it didn't work  to make sure  i tried once again well same result coming .

Answer (score 0):

home.component.html references the variable "orders". This variable does not exist in home.component.ts. When your service returns data you can save it as an instance variable and reference it in your html.

Edit:
I believe you can also bind directly to the observable from your service.

Comment: Thanks for your response @jfarr. i am sorry for the posting little bit edited **home.component.ts** but in actual one **orders** was defined it has some value in it and i was able to print the orders in **home.compoent.html** .
only issue was after sending order to **shared-service** and able to access from **view-order.component.ts**